# С чего можно начать изучение C++?

Tags: c++

Да, такие темы уже не один раз поднимались, но всё-таки меня одолевали сомнения, и я решил задать этот вопрос.
С чего можно начать изучение C++? Язык заинтересовал своим более низкоуровневым, нежели у других языков, взаимодействием с системой и с памятью, очень хотелось бы изучить всё это поподробнее, углубиться в подробности работы ос и т.д. Может быть порекомендуете какие-нибудь хорошие книги, желательно и не "дилетантские", но в тоже время понятные и доступные (ещё бы неплохо было бы чтобы книги были актуальными). Прошу не бить тапками за такой вопрос, в гугле искал, инфы много, но всё так расплывчато и мутно, что ничего оттуда не извлёк.

Comment: С чтения классических книг. Страуструп там

Comment: @Maggot Страуструп для новичка будет уж слишком хардкорно. Лучше Прата и Шлее - оно пишут более простым языком, но книги от того не менее полезные.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я начинал с неё зная си. Если выкинуть главы про мертвую библиотеку то она лучшая ... тогда оста так сначала K&R C потом старина Страуструп